# Is there any way to add a dependency to mvn `process-classes` phase?

Tags: java, maven

The maven **process-classes** phase "*post-process the generated files from compilation, for example to do bytecode enhancement on Java classes*".

1. What's the classpath of the maven 'process-classes' phase?
2. In maven, it is possible to define the scope of each dependency. The scope can be `compile`, `provided`, `runtime`, `test`, `system`, or `import`. However none of those seem to related to the `process-classes` phase. What if a dependency is required at `process-classes` phase? How would I have to declare it so that it would be in the classpath of the `process-classes` phase?

Comment: I do not completely understand your question. If you run a specific plugin in the `process-classes` phase, you can define dependencies of that plugin in the configuration of the plugin. If you are talking about the classpath of the project itself, I do not see how that relates to the `process-classes` phase because you do not post-process classes of your dependencies but your own ones.

Comment: As JF Meier already stated there is no class path related to a life cycle phase. Only a plugin which is bound to life cycle phase can have a classpath which means in other words dependencies...?

Comment: Can explain more in detail what you like to do ? And what kind of problem you are trying to resolve?